# Tag completion unavailable intermittently

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags

Most of the time when I edit tags on Stack Overflow, it echoes normally and I get popups with completions of the tag I'm entering.

But occasionally, it just echoes my typing, and the input scrolls to the left behind the existing tags.

This happens both when editing the tags line from the full question editor, and also when using the "Edit tags" shortcut.

I haven't found any pattern to when this happens. It might be related to my Chrome extensions. I just tried disabling all my extensions and the normal behavior returned. But then when I re-enabled everything, it also worked properly on the same question page. Since the problem is intermittent, it's hard to test whether any particular extension is involved.

I have two extensions related to Stack Exchange: Stack Exchange Deleted Answer Manager and AutoReviewComments.

I have two userscripts in TamperMonkey related to Stack Exchange: stackexchange-tab-editing and Stack Style Code After Edit Refresh.

When the problem happens, I see the following errors in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trigger' of undefined
    at m (tageditornew.en.js?v=931f44c0bfbe:1)
```

Comment: Any errors in the dev console when it's broken?

Comment: @AdamLear I just posted the console error. `tageditornew.en.js` sounds like it's related to tag editing.

Comment: I haven't seen this problem in a while, has it been resolved?

Comment: @Barmar We've been unable to reproduce this. If this is no longer an issue on your end, think we can mark as no-repro or complete.

Comment: It still happens from time to time. I don't know how to trigger it.

Comment: But if you can't reproduce it, maybe it's related to my chrome extensions.

Comment: We've been unable to reproduce this error, so marking as `status-norepro`. If there someone's able to find reproducible steps, we'll investigate again.